# RenderCustomPaint object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: android, html, flutter, android-studio, dart

Below is the class where i have implemented the feature where HTML file will be rendered from the url passed from the previous page. With the click of the floating action button, i want to auto scroll the text of the html. I have tried using singleChildScrollView, Expanded, column but none of the options work for me, Instead I am unable to get the content of the file too and i receive the following error:
RenderCustomPaint object was given an infinite size during layout.

```
class ScrollPage extends StatefulWidget {
      late final  String? url;
      ScrollPage({Key? key,this.url}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ScrollPageState createState() => _ScrollPageState(url);
    }
    
    class _ScrollPageState extends State<ScrollPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    
      late final String? url;
      _ScrollPageState(url);
    
      ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
      bool scroll = false;
      int speedFactor = 20;
    
      _scroll() {
        double maxExtent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
        double distanceDifference = maxExtent - _scrollController.offset;
        double durationDouble = distanceDifference / speedFactor;
    
        _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: Duration(seconds: durationDouble.toInt()),
            curve: Curves.linear);
      }
    
      _toggleScrolling() {
        setState(() {
          scroll = !scroll;
        });
    
        if (scroll) {
          _scroll();
        } else {
          _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.offset,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.linear);
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return    Scaffold(
    
             body: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: NotificationListener(
            onNotification: (notif) {
              if (notif is ScrollEndNotification && scroll) {
                Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  _scroll();
                });
              }
    
              return true;
            },
    
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child:    WebViewPlus (
    
                initialUrl: widget.url,
    
              ),
            ),
          )),
          floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
            _toggleScrolling();
          }), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    
    
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested SingleChildScrollView. Remove the inner single child scroll view and add the controller to the first one

```dart
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return    Scaffold(
    
             body: SingleChildScrollView(
               controller: _scrollController, 
             child: NotificationListener(
            onNotification: (notif) {
              if (notif is ScrollEndNotification && scroll) {
                Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  _scroll();
                });
              }
    
              return true;
            },
              
              child:    WebViewPlus (
                initialUrl: widget.url,
              ),
          )),
          floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
            _toggleScrolling();
          }), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    
    
        );
```

Comment: Now i am getting  RenderAndroidView object was given an infinite size during layout and RenderSemanticsAnnotations object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: I was able to solve by using your code and by adding Container below the SingleChildScrollView but the button when pressed does not work,ie. the scroll doesnot happen.

Comment: Can you print and check if max extent is getting calculated and scroll is getting enabled

Comment: I did print the value of scroll. While pressing the floating action button it was set to true and again when pressed, it was false. So, probably scroll is enabled

Comment: I did print the value of scroll. While pressing the floating action button it was set to true and again when pressed, it was false. So, probably scroll is enabled. and for the maxExtent the value is 0

Comment: Did you assign the scroll controller to the SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: I see that when SingleChildScrollView is used after body, then the maxExtend gives 0 but when used as it the original code , it gives value but gives infinite and error Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt

Comment: Yes I did assign scroll controller

Comment: Below the web view add a container or sized box

Comment: Tried that already but same The following UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt

Comment: Assign a key to a sized box and scroll to that widget. Use that widget as reference. I think the web view isnt giving proper height

Comment: Hmm... I am sorry i did not get you. can you give example

Comment: Scrollable.of(key.currentContext).position.ensureVisible(
        key.currentContext.findRenderObject(),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600)); here key is a global key assigned to a widget

Comment: nothing seems to work. Its getting me go crazy

Comment: What's the error you are getting now?

Answer (score 0):

I think so this will work fine now only remove second SingleChildScrollView from your code this is code example help you..

```
Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (notif) {
          if (notif is ScrollEndNotification && scroll) {
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
              _scroll();
            });
          }

          return true;
        },
        child: WebViewPlus(
          initialUrl: widget.url,
        ),
      )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        _toggleScrolling();
      }),
    )
```